# .htaccess redirect; How to copy value?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I've the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /Search/[my_value]/m(.*) /Search?city=[my_value]
```

`[my_value]` is always the same in both URLs. How can I also copy `[my_value]` from the first URL to the other URL?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the placeholder reference as documented in the alias module:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?Search/([^/]+)/m(.*)$ /Search?city=$1
```

Or you can instead use a simple rewriting rule as offered by the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Search/([^/]+)/m(.*)$ /Search?city=$1 [R=301]
```

Both approaches can be used in the http servers host configuration, or, if really required, in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). You should however definitely prefer the first option.

---

You really should start to read the documentation of the tools you use. Your question is answered in there:

- Alias module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch
- Rewrite Module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question. I often see `$1` in `.htaccess` code. Can I use `$1` multiple times? Or should I only use it once (for a single code) in an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, there is no general answer. As said above: why don't you simply read the documentation? That is what it has been written for: to answer such questions. That documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Answer (score 0):

[`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) uses [Regular Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching.
>
> The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path, and if it matches, the server will substitute any parenthesized matches into the given string and use it as a filename.

This means, to capture part of the request, you must put it in parenthesis `(...`), and then use this as `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the target URL.

---

As @arkascha already has shown, to use `[my_value]`, you capture it with `(.+?)` and add it in the target as `city=$1`. The second part `m(.*)$` could be used as `$2`. But if you don't need it in the target, you can just remove the parenthesis and say `m.*$`, e.g.

```
RedirectMatch ^/Search/(.+?)/m.*$ /Search?city=$1
```

When everything works as it should, you may change the status code to `301`. *Never* test with [`301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).